# Python Pandas Merge Three Dataframes Based on Row Value

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Suppose I have a Dataframe whit this structure:

```
  T1P1_T0   Count T1P1_T1  Count.1 T1P1_T3  Count.2
0     one  1207.0    four     1936     one    644.0
1     two   816.0     two     1601   seven    414.0
2   three   712.0    five     1457     NaN      NaN
3     NaN     NaN     six     4564     NaN      NaN
```

Mi desired output is this:

```
     Element    T1P1_T0  T1P1_T1  T1P1_T3
0        one    1207      NaN    644.0
1        two     816   1601.0      NaN
2      three     712      NaN      NaN
3       four     NaN   1936.0      NaN
4       five           1456.0      NaN
5        six     NaN   4564.0      NaN
6      seven     NaN      NaN    414.0
```

What I've tried, is to separate the initial dataframe into three:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,:2]
df2 = df.iloc[:,2:4]
df3 = df.iloc[:,4:]
```

And try to merge the first two, and then the third one, using different approaches of pd.merge:

for example:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, right_on=df.iloc[:,0], left_on=df.iloc[:,0])
```

but the result is not what I want:

```
   key_0 T1P1_T0   Count T1P1_T1  Count.1
0    one     one  1207.0    four     1936
1    two     two   816.0     two     1601
2  three   three   712.0    five     1457
3    NaN     NaN     NaN     six     4564
```

I don't know how to specify the columns with the element names as the key value for the merge operation.

Any suggestion with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `concat`

```
out = pd.concat([x.set_index(x.columns[0]).iloc[:,0].dropna() for x in [df1,df2,df3]],keys=df.columns[::2],axis=1)
       T1P1_T0  T1P1_T1  T1P1_T3
one     1207.0      NaN    644.0
two      816.0   1601.0      NaN
three    712.0      NaN      NaN
four       NaN   1936.0      NaN
five       NaN   1457.0      NaN
six        NaN   4564.0      NaN
seven      NaN      NaN    414.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding from your data, you can do some more wrangling to get the data into the desired form; also, instead of merging, maybe try concatenating:

As a side note, wondering if the data could be received in a better format, where you did not have to do this wrangling where errors can seep through.

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, :2].dropna()
df1 = (
    df1.set_index(df1.iloc[:, 0].rename("Element"))
    .iloc[:, -1]
    .rename(df1.iloc[:, 0].name)
)
df2 = df.iloc[:, 2:4].dropna()
df2 = (
    df2.set_index(df2.iloc[:, 0].rename("Element"))
    .iloc[:, -1]
    .rename(df2.iloc[:, 0].name)
)
df3 = df.iloc[:, 4:].dropna()
df3 = (
    df3.set_index(df3.iloc[:, 0].rename("Element"))
    .iloc[:, -1]
    .rename(df3.iloc[:, 0].name)
)

df1
Element
one      1207.0
two       816.0
three     712.0
Name: T1P1_T0, dtype: float64

df2
Element
four    1936
two     1601
five    1457
six     4564
Name: T1P1_T1, dtype: int64

df3
Element
one      644.0
seven    414.0
Name: T1P1_T3, dtype: float64
```

Now, concatenate:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis="columns")



       T1P1_T0  T1P1_T1 T1P1_T3
Element         
one     1207.0  NaN     644.0
two     816.0   1601.0  NaN
three   712.0   NaN     NaN
four    NaN     1936.0  NaN
five    NaN     1457.0  NaN
six     NaN     4564.0  NaN
seven   NaN     NaN     414.0
```